# How to export five million records from SQL table to Excel workbook using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, out-of-memory

I want to implement a solution to fetch the data from SQL table which consists of around 5 million rows and 35 columns and export it to an Excel file.

For that, I have written a stored procedure and implemented a paging functionality to retrieve the data.

I am aware that Excel supports approx 1 million records in single sheet, so I want to divide the incoming data into multiple sheets (say 5 sheet for 5 million records).

Are there any other open source Excel packages available to achieve this functionality?

I have tried different Excel packages available for ASP.NET Core, like EPPlus and CLosedXML, but they are consuming too much memory and after some time I am getting Insufficient Memory Buffer exception.

Comment: Why?  What is the data going to be used for?  An excel workbook with 5 million rows, even across 5 sheets, is going to be basically unusable.  Can't you export it as a SQL backup, or CSV?

Comment: Exporting as SQL backup is not an option for me. Coming to CSV, I've tried it but it wasn't useful as I won't be able to view all 5 million records after opening the file.

Comment: What I'm getting at here is that this sounds a lot like an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/)  I'm almost certain you do not want a 5 million row file (be it CSV, or EXCEL)  for it's own sake.  You want to do something with that data once you get it.  If we know what you're actually trying to achieve, a solution might be forthcoming.